# Trisecting a paper using hand and without using a ruler or compass

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

This is a practical problem born while folding a paper.

We can bisect a paper by using only hand.

> $\star$ Easy, fold it so that the two ends (of the length) coincide and press
>   the paper to get the bisector of the length.

Repeating the $\star$ again and again we can divide the paper into $2^n$ (where $n\in\mathbb{N}$) parts using only hand.

But how can we divide the paper into some other(I mean other than $2^n$) number of parts .And particularly,

> How can we divide the paper into three parts? Using only hand and instruments like ruler, compass, protractor etc and cutting away any piece of paper is banned.

I would recommend the reader to take a paper and try it!, it's really interesting!.

Comment: You can find a couple of solutions [here, at the  Wu::Riddles forum](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_easy;action=display;num=1291339015).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this to get three equal parts

[image]

Comment: This won't give you $3$ equal parts. The two end parts will be $3/8$th of the page and the middle part will be $1/4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited my post